# Bash script - user inputs 2 digits seperated by a space; need to verify it's a digit

Tags: regex, bash, digit

Need to have a read statement in BASH that will ask user to input 2 digits on the same line with a space in between. Check if both are digits and there is a space in between.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what have you tried so far? something along the lines of `#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter number one : " n1
read -p "Enter number two : " n2` and then move on from there?

Comment: It's a homework problem, so I need to get them entered at the same time with space in between. so for ex: 12 2

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
result=""
while [[  $result == *" "*  || $result == ""   ]];do
    read -p "Type 2 digits without space:" result;
    echo "Error";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/bin/bash

while :
do
  read -p "digits a b?: "  resp
  if [ -z "${resp}" ] ; then continue;fi

  respCtrl=`echo $resp | sed 's/[^0-9 ]//g'` 
  if [ ! ${#respCtrl} -eq ${#resp} ] ; then  continue ;fi

  set ${resp}
  digit1=$1
  digit2=$2
  if [ "${digit1} ${digit2}" != "${resp}" ] ; then continue;fi

  echo ${digit1} ${digit2}
  break
done
```